# Kotlin Iterate over list of lists

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have a `List<User>` and each user has a `List<Movies>` of all movies that the users watched.

What if we want to get a combination of user id and all watched movides under "drama" genre types, how we could do it without creating a temp mutable List? Is there an operator to iterate over list of lists and get this data?

Comment: Do you mean get the "drama" movies for a specific id or the "drama" movies for all ids?

Comment: I mean "drama" movies for all existing users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your solution should look like this:

```
users.map { user ->
    user.id to user.movies
        .filter { movie -> movie.genre == Genre.DRAMA }
}
.forEach { (userId, dramas) ->
    //do whatever you want with combinations
}
```

It results to combinations of user id and all dramas which user has watched.
For more precise answer please add your `User` and `Movies` classes

Comment: Thank you, I talked with a friend and he showed an example using .flatMapIterable, since I am using RxKotlin. but your answer works too.